# psql passing select count to variable

Tags: postgresql, psql

In postgres Psql want to select count * from a table and pass the value to a variable then use the varaible as input to the function.
i'm trying with this with no success

```
\set cnt "select count(*)/1000 from  table;"

 select fn_something(cnt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in plain SQL by using a CTE.

```
WITH
cnt as (
SELECT
    (count(*)/1000) as cnt
FROM
    table
)
SELECT
    fn_something(SELECT cnt FROM cnt)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by using the subquery as argument to the function:

```
SELECT fn_something((SELECT count(*)/1000 FROM atable));
```

Mind that PostgreSQL will use integer division, i.e. the result will be truncated. If you don't want that, write `1000.0` to get a `double precision` result.